# No EFI system partition configured, BUT I already have it - Lubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, lubuntu

I'm trying to dual-boot-install Lubuntu 20.04.1 through an USB drive created with Rufus on a PC which already has Windows 10 64bit installed on.

My SSD is GPT formatted, I have UEFI, but when I decide to manually install Ubuntu after creating an ext4 partition, I get this error box:[image]

But it's strange, because I already do have an EFI partition installed by Windows as you can see:
[image]

[image]

So what should I do according to you?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Boot to the Lubuntu USB and install/run `boot-repair` following the instructions found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was very easy: I only had to edit the mount point of the already-existing EFI partition (the first one) to '/boot/efi' (without even formatting it) through the Lubuntu installer.

Then the installation proceeded well and smoothly, with dual-boot working fine.